# Should I store my request in asynchronous communication?

Tags: asynchronous, microservices, event-driven

In case I expect a response (event or http). Should I store the request (until I got the response)?

Let's say I send an event to trigger some action and I know that I will (can) receive an event and I can relate both events via a `reference`. Events can be replaced with HTTP, just a detail.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how the error recovery scenario looks like (for example in case the recipient is down, the request is lost etc.), i.e. in which cases it is necessary to repeat the exact same request.

If the response is needed for continuing and if it is cumbersome or expensive to regenerate it, it does make sense to store it for repeating.

If however the requesting service can proceed without having received the response and just send another request at a later time, there is no need to store the original request.

You might also consider a mechanism in between the services to take care of the error handling for you (such as a message queue).